# Why does setInterval return NaN?

Tags: reactjs, state, nan, updating

The task is to create a ticking time bomb app using the state to determine whether the current count is less than 8 and divisible by 2.

When the count is less than 8 and divisible by 2, it should display the word "tick". When the count isn't divisible by 2, it should display "tock".  If the count goes equal to or above 8, "BOOM!!!"

I've logged the state to see what it is being set as and at first the initial state *0* gets logged the word *tick* is displayed but immediately after I keep getting *NaN* as the log and the word **BOOM!!!** gets displayed.

```
    import React from 'react';

class Bomb extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        count: this.count++,
      });
    }, 1000);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  displayTickorTock() {
    const currentCount = this.state.count;
    const tick = <p>'tick'</p>;
    const tock = <p>'tock'</p>;
    let tickOrTock;

    if(currentCount % 2 === 0) {
      tickOrTock = tick;
    } else if (currentCount % 2 !== 0) {
      tickOrTock = tock;
    } else {
      tickOrTock = <p>'BOOM!!!!'</p>
    }
    return tickOrTock;
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.count);
    return <div>{this.displayTickorTock()}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, I don't see a condition for 8 and above. So there won't be any BOOM!. Secondly, if your state updates in some given intervals of time (frequently), its a good practice to set state using a callback function like `this.setState((s) => ({ count: s.count + 1 }));` . This will go inside your `setInterval`, replacing the current code. [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-hodgkin-i08s8?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @boop_the_snoot thank you so much for the advice!  I set the state using a callback as you said and it helped.  I did not know about that so great tip!